# How to understand if $a-c \lt b \lt a+c$ then $b-c \lt a \lt b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, inequality, confidence-interval

I'm learning the concept of confidence interval. One of the important inference is that "the probability that sample mean is within two standard deviation of population mean equals to 95%." is equivalent to "there is a 95% probability that population mean is within two standard  deviation of sample mean."

It seems the logic is if $a-c \lt b \lt a+c$ then to $b-c \lt a \lt b+c$ where a = population mean, b = sample mean and c = 2SD.

I don't understand.

Comment: I reformatted your post, could you please verify whether the inequalities within the title (or the body) were as you intended them to be? Further, what do you mean by "then to" in the title and the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu$ and $\bar{x}$ be the population and sample means, respectively. The confidence interval:
$$\bar{x}-ME<\mu<\bar{x}+ME \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where $ME=z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ is the margin of error. Also, $ME=z_{\alpha/2}SE$, where $SE$ is the standard error.

Multiply $(1)$ by $-1$:
$$-\bar{x}+ME>-\mu>-\bar{x}-ME \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Add $\mu+\bar{x}$ to $(2)$:
$$\mu+ME>\bar{x}>\mu -ME \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$ 
Hence, $(1),(2),(3)$ are equivalent.

Comment: @Kevin, Yes, the assumption is called the Central Limit Theorem, by which the sample size and the sampling distribution requirements must be satisfied. In solving problems on hypothesis testing (which is equivalent to the confidence interval), when the population SD is not known, the sample SD and $t$ table are recommended to be used instead.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my question by accident. Here it is: "The standard deviation of the sample is different from that of the population (at least in most of the cases). We use the sample standard deviation here. Is this mean that the confidence interval is still a huge assumption?" Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"$a-c<b<a+c$" is a placeholder for "$(a-c<b)\land (b<a+c)$", which in turn is equivalent to $(a<b+c)\land (b-c<a)$ by carrying the appropriate term to the other sides.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is that if $a-c<b<a+c$ then $-a+c>-b>-a-c$ (multiplying by $-1$ reverses all the inequalities) and then adding $a+b$ to all terms gives $b+c>a>b-c$, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Both formulae are equivalent to $|a - b| < c$.

Answer (score 0):

$$|\hat p - mean| < 2*(SD)$$
means "the distance from $\hat p$ to the mean (which is symmetric, signless) is less than 2 standard deviations".  Using inequality rules:

> $\hat p - mean < 2*(SD)$ **or** $\hat p - mean > -2 * (standard deviations)$

therefore

> $\hat p < mean + 2*(SD)$ **or** $\hat p > mean - 2 * (SD)$

or

> $b < a + c$ **or** $b > a - c$

, as you would write it (your first expression).

You can also collect $a$ to one side and see how it affects $b$ and $c$.

The compound inequalities mean the same thing when you write with **or**s.  But you write your equations as if these **or**s were **and**s, and that's why you're confused.

Great to learn about confidence intervals by the way.